# Adding UPDATE and DELETE functionality in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can i add update and delete functionality in DataGridView? I want to add 2 buttons with that functionality.

Here's how my DataGridView works:

```
const string filename = @"database.db";
const string sql = "select * from legal_tbl;";
var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + filename + ";Version=3;");
try
{
   conn.Open();
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   var da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, conn);
   da.Fill(ds);
   DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
   this.data_view.DataSource = dt;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex + "");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Update functionality you need to write code for : `RowEditing`, `RowUpdating` and `RowCancelingEdit`

You also need to create `EditItemTemplate` in the grid code in aspx file.

For Delete functionality you need to write code for : `RowDeleting`

[Refer this](http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource10-How-to-perform-insert-update-delete-and-select-rows-in-ASPNET-gridview-c.aspx)